# Getting a mock Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mocking, phpunit

I've been trying all day to write some tests for a class that parses a custom DSL and creates DQL queries.

My class requires that I pass in a `queryBuilder` which it then uses to build the query and return it.

The problem I have is that

- to get a `queryBuilder` I need an `entityManager`
- to get an `entityManager` I need a connection
- to get a connection I need a database

I'd rather that my unit tests didn't rely on a database so I've been trying to create a mock `queryBuilder` using `PHPUnit` but `queryBuilder` seems to rely on the `entityManager` which in turn relies on a connection.

So 2 questions:
Is there a better way to dynamically construct queries in Doctrine 2?
Is there a way to get a working `queryBuilder` without an `entityManager` (or at least without a real database)?

Comment: if you'll mock QueryBuilder with MockBuilder and call disableOriginalConstructor method - then you don't need any entity manager. It will be easier answer to your question if you post class which you want test

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to do it with PHPUnit, but I would recommend checking out [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) for your PHP mocking needs. It's a really powerful library which allows you to mock the EntityManager pretty easily, and therefore anything that it will return.

For your use case, you can easily create a Mock entity manager than will return you a mock query builder:

```
$mockEm = \Mockery::mock('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
$mockQb = \Mockery::mock('\Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder');
$mockEm->shouldReceive('createQueryBuilder')->andReturn($mockQb);
```

Then you can use Mockery's core functionality to set the expectations you require for your unit test.

On a slight aside, you also get the option of using a 'passive' EntityManager mock, in case you want to unit test a function which contains some database logic, but you don't actually want to go to the database in your unit test.

```
public function getPassiveEntityManagerMock() {
    return \Mockery::mock('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager',
                          array('getRepository' => new FakeRepository(),
                                'getClassMetadata' => (object)array('name' => 'aClass'),
                                'persist' => null,
                                'flush' => null));
}
```

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/wowo/1331789) a suggested way of doing it with PHPUnit, but I haven't tried it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating my own mock query builder; it may have been possible to get the same functionality using PHPUnits mocking framework but this is wha I ended up with:

```
<?php
namespace MyNameSpace\Tests\Mocks;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class MockQueryBuilder extends QueryBuilder {

    protected $expr;
    protected $paramReflect;

    public function __construct($expr) {
        $this->expr = $expr;
        $this->paramReflect = new \ReflectionProperty('Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder', 'parameters'); 
        $this->paramReflect->setAccessible(true);
        $this->paramReflect->setValue($this, new ArrayCollection());
    }

    /*
     * @return Query\Expr
     */
    public function expr() {
        return $this->expr;
    }

    public function getEntityManager() {
        return null;
    }

    public function getQuery() {
        return array(
            'parameters' => clone $this->paramReflect->getValue($this),
            'dql' => $this->getDQL(),

        );
    }

}
```